# Can't access mysql on a pc connected over LAN?

Tags: networking, mysql, ping

these are the details of my device

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.110
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
```

and i want to access mysql  on device with ip

```
IPv4 = 192.168.1.24
```

ping is also not working

```
C:\Users\ITDESK>ping 192.168.1.24

Pinging 192.168.1.24 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.24:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Check firewall on the target machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to checking and fixing the firewall as djsmiley2k mentioned, you should setup MySQL to accept connections from other computers than localhost.

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO db_user @'192.168.1.110' IDENTIFIED BY 'db_passwd';`

Will allow the user *db_user* to do **everything** on **ALL** databases if he can present the correct password. You should over think this of course if you switch to production environment, as granting everything everywhere is "kind of dangerous".

You also should configure your MySQL to bind to address `0.0.0.0` which means every IP the host has. Per default it would be set to `127.0.0.1` (only connections from localhost) You can change this value in the `my.cnf` located at `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Your "IP stlye" suggests you are trying this in a private network, maybe you have to configure your router to allow traffic between computers, as some routers (the FritzBox brand for example) disallow this kind of traffic per default.

Comment: Glad I could help you